# Arranging 3 types of balls with given conditions.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, algorithms, combinations, dynamic-programming

> There are 3 types of balls black, white and green. Find the number of ways of arranging $n$ such balls such that
>
> - black, white adjacent pairs occur $a$ times,
> - black, green adjacent pairs occur $b$ times,
> - green, black adjacent pairs occur $c$ times,
> - green, white adjacent pairs occur $d$ times,
> - white, green adjacent pairs occur $e$ times,
> - white, black adjacent pairs occur $f$ times,
> - $0\le a,b,c,d,e,f\le 10$, and
> - $n \le 100000$.

**Is there a better approach to this problem than what I have already done?**

My approach:

Suppose $n = 10$;
I am going for $1$ condition at a time.

1. All  are zero, so we left with $3$ permutations i.e. $BBB\dotso$ $n$ times, $WWW\dotso$ $n$, and $GGG\dotso$ $n$.
2. All are $1$.  Then we can have $6(n-1)$ permutations, e.g. if there are only black ($B$) and white ($W$) balls, then permutations will be like $BBBBBWWWWW$ or $BWWWWW$, or something like $\dotso BW\dotso$, so $(n-1)$.
3. Some of my observations are that there will not be any permutations which contain (ONLY) any of these following pairs:
   $BW$ and $BG$ not possible because $BW\dotso BG$ should also contain some other pairs to coexist like $WB$ or $BWWWBG$.
   So in this way only 2 pairs available are:
   $$
       BW\dotso WG \\
       BG\dotso GW \\
       GW\dotso WG \\
       GB\dotso BG \\
       WB\dotso BW \\
       WG\dotso GB \\
      $$
   for a total of $6$ pairs and they can only exist only $1$ time.
   So this type of permutations will be $x(n-1)$ where $x$ is the number of pairs that can be formed, since there are different values for each of them.

In this way I trying to figure out all other possibilities. I need a better solution which gives me permutations when $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are given.

Comment: please show your effort

Comment: I tried it checking one condition at a time.
 1. If all the limits are zero then number of possible arrangements  will be 3
either BBBBB , GGGGGG, or WWWWW.
2. one more thing BG cannot coexist only with BW there will be at least 1 G-B or 1 G-B and 1BW and 1GW 
I was trying to solve it in this way but thought there must be some easier way to do this.

Comment: @Lee I have updated with my approach

Comment: Is the arrangement linear or circular?

Comment: @user Arrangement is linear

Comment: Can Anyone answer this question ?